# Cannot find name 'XXX'

Tags: angular, typescript, module, components

I am getting the error "Cannot find name 'Calendar Component'" in my app.module.ts file when trying to add a route to a component exported by another module.

Here is my app.module.ts file

```
// Module Import Statements //
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { CalendarModule } from './scripts/calendar/calendar.module';

// Component Import Statements //
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Routes Declaration Statements //

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CalendarModule,
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
           path: 'calendar', component: CalendarComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and here is my calendar.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { CalendarComponent } from './calendar.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [CalendarComponent],
  exports: [CalendarComponent]
})
export class CalendarModule { }
```

As you can see, my calendar component is both declared and exported in my calendar.Module.ts file (calendar.component.ts exists, but I left it out for clarity of my question). Why, then, can't my app module recognize and interpret the component I attempt to pass it in my routes array?

I am using Angular v5.2.0 if it's any help.

Answer (score 0):

a. You have not imported CalenderComponent in app.module.ts.

b. I would suggest try implementing Calender feature as child routes

Ref:   https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-4-crisis-center-feature

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an import statement in the app.module.ts file.

```
import { CalendarComponent } from '[location of calendar component]';
```

There is a difference between TypeScript `imports` statement and Angular's ngModule `imports` array.

`import { .. } from '@angular/..'` are for typescript imports, which means you are going to use some of the identifiers declared in a typescript file available at the '@angular/..' location (mostly index.ts in that location)

`imports: [ module1, module2, ... ]` specifies a list of modules whose exported components/directives/pipes should be available to templates in the current module.

> Modules are executed within their own scope, not in the global scope; this means that variables, functions, classes, etc. declared in a module are not visible outside the module unless they are explicitly exported using one of the export forms. Conversely, to consume a variable, function, class, interface, etc. exported from a different module, it has to be imported using one of the import forms.
>   Blockquote

Kindly follow through [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) link for more clarity.

Comment: I had figured that I needed to also import it, just didn't understand why, so thank you for the explanation. As for services that I need, do I export them from a module where they are declared, and then import them in the app.module.ts in a similar fashion? -- So importing a whole module, as in the case of my calendar module, does not bring with it the component exports of that module (as I still need to import them from their initial export location -- in this case the calendar.component.ts)?

Comment: You don't need to do typescript import of services declared in other modules in the app.module.ts as long as you are not using them in app.module.ts (just the app.module typescript file).